# I have a code break in this fragment but I can't solve it.. It showing that I have null reference ob set text but when I debug I see data

Tags: java, android, replace, fragment

```
## fragment 1
```

I am geting null reference on setText on TextView control but I can't find a reason why...

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import ba.fit.app.hci_odbrana.R;
import ba.fit.app.hci_odbrana.helper.MyRunnable;
import ba.fit.app.hci_odbrana.helper.Util;
import ba.fit.app.hci_odbrana.podaci.KorisnikVM;
import ba.fit.app.hci_odbrana.podaci.OpstinaVM;
import ba.fit.app.hci_odbrana.podaci.PosiljkaVM;


public class PosiljaocFragment extends Fragment {
    public static final String NEKI_KLJUC = "nekiKljuc";
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER


    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;
    private TextView viewImePosiljaoca;
    private TextView adresaPosiljaoca;
    private PosiljkaVM posiljkaVM = new PosiljkaVM();
    private OpstinaVM opstina;


    public PosiljaocFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static PosiljaocFragment newInstance(PosiljkaVM posiljka) {
        PosiljaocFragment fragment = new PosiljaocFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putSerializable(NEKI_KLJUC, posiljka);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            posiljkaVM = (PosiljkaVM) getArguments().getSerializable(NEKI_KLJUC);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_posiljaoc, container, false);

        viewImePosiljaoca = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.viewImePosiljaoca);
        adresaPosiljaoca = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.viewAdresaPosiljaoca);
        final Button btnPromjeniPosiljaoca = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnPromjeniPosiljaoca);
        Button btnDalje = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnDalje);

        if (posiljkaVM.posljiaoc != null){
            viewImePosiljaoca.setText(posiljkaVM.posljiaoc.getIme() + " " + posiljkaVM.posljiaoc.getPrezime());
            adresaPosiljaoca.setText(posiljkaVM.posljiaoc.getAdresa() + " - " + posiljkaVM.posljiaoc.getOpstinaVM().getNaziv());
        }


        btnDalje.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                btnDaljeClick();
            }
        });

        btnPromjeniPosiljaoca.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                btnPromjeniPosiljaocaClick();
            }
        });


        return view;
    }

    private void btnDaljeClick() {
        if (posiljkaVM.primaoc == null){
            posiljkaVM.primaoc = new KorisnikVM("", "", new OpstinaVM(0,"",""), "");
        }

        if (posiljkaVM.posljiaoc == null){
            posiljkaVM.posljiaoc = new KorisnikVM(posiljkaVM.posljiaoc.getIme(), posiljkaVM.posljiaoc.getPrezime(), opstina, "");
        }

        Util.otvoriFragmentKaoReplace(getActivity(), R.id.fragmentPlace, PrimaocFragment.newInstance(posiljkaVM));
    }

    private void btnPromjeniPosiljaocaClick() {
        MyRunnable<KorisnikVM> callback = new MyRunnable<KorisnikVM>() {
            @Override
            public void run(KorisnikVM result) {
                posiljkaVM.posljiaoc = result;
                viewImePosiljaoca.setText(result.getIme() + " " + result.getPrezime());
                adresaPosiljaoca.setText(result.getAdresa() + " - " + result.getOpstinaVM().getNaziv());
                posiljkaVM.posljiaoc.setIme(result.getIme());
                posiljkaVM.posljiaoc.setPrezime(result.getPrezime());
                posiljkaVM.posljiaoc.setOpstinaVM(result.getOpstinaVM());
                posiljkaVM.posljiaoc.setAdresa(result.getAdresa());
            }
        };

        Util.otvoriFragmentKaoDijalog(getActivity(), KorisniciFragment.newInstance(callback));
    }

}



### dialog fragment

package ba.fit.app.hci_odbrana.fragmenti;


import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

import ba.fit.app.hci_odbrana.R;
import ba.fit.app.hci_odbrana.helper.MyRunnable;
import ba.fit.app.hci_odbrana.podaci.KorisnikVM;
import ba.fit.app.hci_odbrana.podaci.Storage;

public class KorisniciFragment extends DialogFragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private MyRunnable<KorisnikVM> callback;
    private String mParam2;
    private EditText txtImePrezime;
    private ListView listKorisnici;
    private TextView linija1;
    private TextView linija2;
    private List<KorisnikVM> podaci;


    public KorisniciFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static KorisniciFragment newInstance(MyRunnable<KorisnikVM> myCallback) {
        KorisniciFragment fragment = new KorisniciFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putSerializable(ARG_PARAM1, myCallback);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            callback = (MyRunnable<KorisnikVM>) getArguments().getSerializable(ARG_PARAM1);

        }
        setStyle(STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.MojDijalog);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_korisnici, container, false);

        txtImePrezime = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txtImePrezime);
        listKorisnici = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listKorisnici);
        Button btnTrazi = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnTrazi);

        popuniPodatke("");
        btnTrazi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                btnTraziClick();
            }
        });

        listKorisnici.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                KorisnikVM x = podaci.get(position);
                getDialog().dismiss();
                callback.run(x);
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    private void btnTraziClick() {
        popuniPodatke(txtImePrezime.getText().toString());
    }

    private void popuniPodatke(String name) {
        podaci = Storage.getKorisniciByName(name);

        listKorisnici.setAdapter(new BaseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return podaci.size();
            }

            @Override
            public Object getItem(int position) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int position) {
                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
                KorisnikVM x = podaci.get(position);

                if( view == null)
                {
                    final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.stavka_korisnici, viewGroup, false);
                }

                linija1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.linija1);
                linija2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.linija2);

                linija1.setText(x.getIme() + " " + x.getPrezime());
                linija2.setText(x.getOpstinaVM().getNaziv() + " - " + x.getAdresa());

                return view;
            }
        });
    }

}


## Fragment 2
```

Here everything works fine and it's very similar to first one.

```
package ba.fit.app.hci_odbrana.fragmenti;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import ba.fit.app.hci_odbrana.R;
import ba.fit.app.hci_odbrana.helper.MyRunnable;
import ba.fit.app.hci_odbrana.helper.Util;
import ba.fit.app.hci_odbrana.podaci.KorisnikVM;
import ba.fit.app.hci_odbrana.podaci.PosiljkaVM;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Use the {@link PrimaocFragment#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class PrimaocFragment extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private PosiljkaVM mParam1;
    private TextView viewImePrimaoca;
    private TextView adresaPrimaoca;


    public PrimaocFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static PrimaocFragment newInstance(PosiljkaVM param1) {
        PrimaocFragment fragment = new PrimaocFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putSerializable(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = (PosiljkaVM) getArguments().getSerializable(ARG_PARAM1);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_primaoc, container, false);

        viewImePrimaoca = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.viewImePrimaoca);
        adresaPrimaoca = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.viewAdresaPrimaoca);
        final Button btnPromjeniPrimaoca = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnPromjeniPrimaoca);
        final Button btnNazad = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnNazad);
        final Button btnDalje2 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnDalje2);

        if (getArguments() != null){
            viewImePrimaoca.setText(mParam1.primaoc.getIme() + " " + mParam1.primaoc.getPrezime());
            adresaPrimaoca.setText(mParam1.primaoc.getAdresa() + " - " + mParam1.primaoc.getOpstinaVM().getNaziv());
        }

        btnDalje2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                btnDalje2Click();
            }
        });

        btnNazad.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                btnNazadClick();
            }
        });

        btnPromjeniPrimaoca.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                btnPromjeniPrimaocaClick();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    private void btnNazadClick() {
        Util.otvoriFragmentKaoReplace(getActivity(), R.id.fragmentPlace, PosiljaocFragment.newInstance(mParam1));
    }

    private void btnDalje2Click() {
        Util.otvoriFragmentKaoReplace(getActivity(), R.id.fragmentPlace, PaketFragment.newInstance(mParam1));
    }

    private void btnPromjeniPrimaocaClick() {
        MyRunnable<KorisnikVM> callback = new MyRunnable<KorisnikVM>() {
            @Override
            public void run(KorisnikVM result) {
                mParam1.primaoc = result;
                viewImePrimaoca.setText(result.getIme() + " " + result.getPrezime());
                adresaPrimaoca.setText(result.getAdresa() + " - " + result.getOpstinaVM().getNaziv()); //here is where I get that null reference
            }
        };

        Util.otvoriFragmentKaoDijalog(getActivity(), KorisniciFragment.newInstance(callback));
    }




}


## package fragment
```

This is for showing some details on package that is been sent when you chose sender and receiver

```
public class PaketFragment extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private PosiljkaVM mParam1;
    private EditText txtMasa;
    private EditText txtNapomena;


    public PaketFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static PaketFragment newInstance(PosiljkaVM param1) {
        PaketFragment fragment = new PaketFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putSerializable(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = (PosiljkaVM) getArguments().getSerializable(ARG_PARAM1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_paket, container, false);

        txtMasa = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txtMasa);
        txtNapomena = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txtNapomena);
        final Button btnZavrsi = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnZavrsi);
        final Button btnNazad2 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnNazad2);

        btnNazad2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                btnNazad2Click();
            }
        });


        btnZavrsi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                btnZavrsiClick();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    private void btnZavrsiClick() {
        try {
            mParam1.masa = Float.parseFloat(txtMasa.getText().toString());
            mParam1.napomena = txtNapomena.getText().toString();

            Util.otvoriFragmentKaoReplace(getActivity(), R.id.fragmentPlace, PosiljaocFragment.newInstance(mParam1));

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Uspješno spremljena pošiljka!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }catch (Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Greška: " + e.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

    private void btnNazad2Click() {
        Util.otvoriFragmentKaoReplace(getActivity(), R.id.fragmentPlace, PrimaocFragment.newInstance(mParam1));
    }

}
```

That's it.. hope someone can help me. Have a pleasant day.

Comment: Please create a [MCVE] (with emphasis on **minimal**).

Comment: I really can't tell given this example. I noticed you have a Runnable. Is the null pointer occurring from a click on a dialog from method btnPromjeniPosiljaocaClick(). If so then maybe the activity containing the fragment that you want to update has finished.